# Odoo 13:- HTTP controller type ="http" request type application/json not accepted

Tags: python, json, http-post, odoo, odoo-13

I write a odoo program in python, this way request  type **text/plain** is working. And **application/json** request work in any other odoo version(Odoo 15,Odoo 16) .But odoo 13 application/json request  not working.

**My odoo python controller code here:-**

```
class CamsAttendance(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/sample/sample_json/', method=["POST"], csrf=False, auth='public', type="http")
    def generate_attendance(self, **params):
            data = json.loads(request.httprequest.data)
            json_object = json.dumps(data)
            sample = json.loads(json_object)

            print(sample['sample_code'])
            return "process competed" //example
```

view the image on request  and response data via postman:-
[image]

**Request application/json data:-**
(sample request)

```
{
    "sample_code":"sample_code"
}
```

**Response data:-**

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "error": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "Odoo Server Error",
        "data": {
            "name": "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest",
            "debug": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"C:\\odoo 13\\Odoo 13.0\\server\\odoo\\http.py\", line 624, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"C:\\odoo 13\\Odoo 13.0\\server\\odoo\\http.py\", line 310, in _handle_exception\n    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])\n  File \"C:\\odoo 13\\Odoo 13.0\\server\\odoo\\tools\\pycompat.py\", line 14, in reraise\n    raise value\n  File \"C:\\odoo 13\\Odoo 13.0\\server\\odoo\\http.py\", line 669, in dispatch\n    result = self._call_function(**self.params)\n  File \"C:\\odoo 13\\Odoo 13.0\\server\\odoo\\http.py\", line 318, in _call_function\n    raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg % params)\nwerkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: <function CamsAttendance.generate_attendance at 0x0644C930>, /cams/biometric-api3.0: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'\n",
            "message": "400 Bad Request: <function CamsAttendance.generate_attendance at 0x0644C930>, /cams/biometric-api3.0: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'",
            "arguments": [],
            "exception_type": "internal_error",
            "context": {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Another way try :-**
I note the error ** 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'"** in the response and i change the code contoroller code on
@http.route('/sample/sample_json/', method=["POST"], csrf=False, auth='public', **type="json"**)

But,

**Response:-**

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "result": "process competed"
}
```

**
but i want :-**
"process competed

Mainly this problem Odoo 13 only. And i what process the code and expecting text
message the response

Comment: the response is correct, all you need is to parse it from your client

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the `type` of the controller route to `json`?

Also see the [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/addons/http.html#odoo.http.route)

> odoo.http.route(route=None, **kw)
>
> Decorator marking the
> decorated method as being a handler for requests. The method must be
> part of a subclass of Controller.
>
> Parameters
>
> route – string or array. The route part that will determine
> which http requests will match the decorated method. Can be a single
> string or an array of strings. See werkzeug’s routing documentation
> for the format of route expression (
> http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/ ).
>
> **type – The type of request, can be 'http' or 'json'.**
>
> auth –
>
> > The type of authentication method, can on of the following:
> >
> > user: The user must be authenticated and the current request will
> > perform using the rights of the user.
> >
> > public: The user may or may not be authenticated. If she isn’t, the
> > current request will perform using the shared Public user.
> >
> > none: The method is always active, even if there is no database.
> > Mainly used by the framework and authentication modules. There request
> > code will not have any facilities to access the database nor have any
> > configuration indicating the current database nor the current user.
>
> methods – A sequence of http methods this route applies to. If not
> specified, all methods are allowed.
>
> cors – The Access-Control-Allow-Origin cors directive value.
>
> csrf (bool) –
>
> > Whether CSRF protection should be enabled for the route.
> >
> > Defaults to True. See CSRF Protection for more.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation.I was learn about the documentation.But not working for odoo 13.so i change to content-type="text/plain" in request url .

Answer (score 0):

As CZoellner said, you need to change `type` to `json`.
You also need to include `OPTIONS` in request methods and enable cors for the request.

```
@http.route('/sample/sample_json/', type='json', auth='public', cors='*', csrf=False, methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
```

Ensure your request body follows odoo's syntax

```
{
  jsonrpc: 2.0,
  params: {
    sample_code: "sample_code"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the  answer.I use only normal json format. so use change to plain text in request url.